# Windows 10 Bootcamp Partition Unseen By OS X

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition

I've look around here and Apple's support community, but can't find my exact issue. I recently reinstalled Windows 10 to my MacBook Pro (Mid 2012), added a partition to start on installing Linux, and now OS X doesn't see the Windows 10 partition at all. I can still hold down alt/option to start it up, but I would like to have the option to have it automatically start to Windows 10, which I don't anymore.

sudo fdisk /dev/disk0 returned the following:

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 29185/255/63 [468862128 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE    0   0   2 -   25 127  14 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
 2: AF   25 127  15 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  233553880] HFS+        
*3: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 234225664 -     204800] HPFS/QNX/AUX
 4: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 234430464 -  234428416] HPFS/QNX/AUX
```

sudo gdisk /dev/disk0 returned this:

```
Disk /dev/disk0: 468862128 sectors, 223.6 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): F33219B5-A986-430B-8674-23055706EF16
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 468862094
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 234693781 sectors (111.9 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          409640       233963519   111.4 GiB   AF00  Untitled
   3       234225664       234430463   100.0 MiB   0700  BOOTCAMP
```

Of course, Disk Utility was SO helpful by showing this:
[image: Disk Utility being Helpful]

I don't want to reinstall Windows 10 AGAIN, and I can't seem to find any information that actually helps with this issue. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated, you can hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key at startup to invoke the Startup Manager. If you hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key while selecting one of the displayed partitions, then chosen partition will become the new default startup partition.

Comment: The actual answer I ended up using was the exact one I wanted to avoid. I installed Refind and am successfully using it to control boot up. I do appreciate this option, though I'm not sure it would work if OS X doesn't see the partition I would be choosing.